Is BNF grammar in TeXbook correct?
In answer to exercise 24.3 it is said that 1\baselineskip coerces \baselineskip to
a <dimen>.
Therefore, according to rules on pp.268--271 of TeXbook, we must have this chain:
<glue> ->  <dimen> <stretch> <shrink>
<dimen> -> <optional_signs> <unsigned_dimen>
<optional_signs> -> <optional_spaces>
<optional_spaces> -> <empty>
<unsigned_dimen> -> <coerced_dimen>
<coerced_dimen> -> <internal_glue>
<internal_glue> -> <glue_parameter>
<glue_parameter> -> \baselineskip
<stretch> -> <optional_spaces>
<shrink> -> <optional_spaces>

But 1\baselineskip does not fit this grammar.
Is the grammar wrong in TeXbook?

It actually does fit, following this chain
⟨glue⟩ → ⟨dimen⟩ ⟨stretch⟩ ⟨shrink⟩
  ⟨stretch⟩ → ⟨optional spaces⟩
  ⟨shrink⟩ → ⟨optional spaces⟩
⟨dimen⟩ → ⟨optional signs⟩ ⟨unsigned dimen⟩
⟨unsigned dimen⟩ → ⟨normal dimen⟩
⟨normal dimen⟩ → ⟨factor⟩ ⟨unit of measure⟩
  ⟨factor⟩ → ⟨normal integer⟩  (this is the `1`)
⟨unit of measure⟩ → ⟨optional spaces⟩ ⟨internal unit⟩
⟨internal unit⟩ → ⟨internal glue⟩
⟨internal glue⟩ → ⟨glue parameter⟩
⟨glue parameter⟩ → \baselineskip

The reason why the 1 forces remove the stretch and shrink part is because if you don't have the 1 (just +) then the following path is followed
⟨glue⟩ → ⟨optional signs⟩ ⟨internal glue⟩
⟨internal glue⟩ → ⟨glue parameter⟩
⟨glue parameter⟩ → \baselineskip


In which point of the chain in your answer does coercing happen? Could you think of any example which follows ⟨unsigned dimen⟩ → ⟨coerced dimen⟩ path?

@IgorLiferenko It's because the ⟨internal glue⟩ is passed through a ⟨dimen⟩ phase it is converted to a dimen. The ⟨unsigned dimen⟩ → ⟨coerced dimen⟩ path is used when e.g. you assign e.g. \dimen1=\baselineskip. I think there's no reason why the ⟨dimen⟩ that appears in ⟨glue⟩ → ⟨dimen⟩ ⟨stretch⟩ ⟨shrink⟩ should be a coerced dimen.

I'm not sure the general English description of something being "coerced" is the same as a grammar production having <coerced...  so I think that this path through the grammar is correct. the fact that a  removes the stretch is a rather different type of coercion than the coercion steps marked with <coerced...`. which relate to treating a glue as a dimen or a dimen as a number

@DavidCarlisle This "different type of coercion" is described in answer to exercise 24.4: ⟨internal glue⟩ is coerced to a dimension when it appears as an ⟨internal unit⟩.

1\baselineskip can not be a glue as the rules for glue do not involve a factor (to be more precise: it can not be a glue with shrink + stretch). So the question is if it can be a dimen and that is easy to verify:
<dimen> -> 
<unsigned dimen> -> 
<normal dimen> -> 
<factor><unit of measure> ->
1 <unit of measure> ->
1 <internal unit> -> 
1 <internal glue> ->
1 <glue parameter> ->
1 \baselineskip

To expand a bit let's assume
\baselineskip = 10pt plus 5pt minus 3pt
\parskip = 1\baselineskip 
\showthe\parskip % gives > 10.0pt.

The parskip assigment is looking for a glue. A glue is either <optional signs><internal glue> (that doesn't fit here) or <dimen><stretch><shrink>.
As written above 1\baselineskip follows the rules of a dimen, and as a dimen it has value 10pt. The assignment will then look for explicit stretch or shrink but there aren't there, so we get 10pt. If you want stretch/shrink you have to add it: \parskip = 1\baselineskip plus 4pt minus 3pt.

You are trying to deduce logically where coersion happens: if stretch and shrink follow dimen in first rule, they cannot be present after unit of measure, which can be a glue. Do I understand your answer right?

@IgorLiferenko not sure what you mean but I expanded a bit.
